# jQuery v1.7.1 is not filling the content in Firefox 3.6

Tags: jquery, firefox

I wrote some code which fills values from a json to a form. The format of JSON is {"id","value"}. The id corresponds to the respective html element. I used a $.each loop to go through the JSON to fill the respective elements.

This code is working fine with FF8 + and IE 7+ but it is not working with FF 3.6 ? Does any body have any idea ?

my code uses the simple JSON function

```
$("#id").val('result');
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was $("#id").val = 'result';

Comment: I found out the reason. I have few console.log() statement in my code and they are causing the problem. I found the problem by going through the error logs in Error Console of Firefox.